# Why does TypeScript need Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

This is probably not the best question but I'm still completely new to JS. I'm interested in Typescript (being an AS3 dev), but I keep reading that I need to instal node.js to compile it? why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TypeScript is a language that compiles into JavaScript.  The compiler that does this, appears to be written (or at least distributed) in JavaScript.  And node.js is the most common way to execute JavaScript outside a browser.

The typescript compiler is simply JavaScript, which is executed by node.js to compile things.

Why is that, you ask? Well, because that's what the developers of the compiler chose to write their compiler in.  It could have been any language they wanted really.

The compiler is actually written *in TypeScript*. Yeah, a compiler written in the language it's supposed to compile, which may seem strange. But how that works is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Again probably dumb question, but could't a browser then compile it?

Comment: @Phil Probably, but not necessarily. Node.js exposes APIs that aren't in the browser, and if the compiler uses any of those, it wouldn't work.  But in theory, the task of taking this string of TypeScript and spitting out another string of JavaScript would work fine in a browser. In fact [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts) works this way. But you shouldn't need a browser to compile a TypeScript file on your harddrive :)

Comment: Actually TypeScript's compiler _does_ run in the browser.  That's exactly why this works: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

Comment: The compiler is written in TypeScript. You need a JavaScript runtime that gives you access to the file system if you want to create files and update files, which is why you need node.js (or similar) to do a proper job. You can do everything except save files using browser script engines.

Comment: "Yeah, a compiler written in the language it's supposed to compile, weird but possible" -- actually it's not that weird. It's called bootstrapping, and is a very common way of creating a compiler.